# Office-js getFileAsync Support in Excel for Mac

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js

Edit: Support appears to be added now. It is working in Excel for Mac.

I've implemented a function for Excel Online using `Office.context.document.getFileAsync(...)` and it works perfectly fine. Unfortunately, it appears that `document.getFileAsync()` is not supported in Excel for Mac. I missed this in my initial research into whether or not this approach would work.

I'm hoping I'm just doing something wrong. Would anyone be able to confirm that it is not supported in Excel for Mac 2016? And, if it isn't supported, give an idea of when or if it will ever be supported?

Comment: This API is now implemented on Macbook. July build of Macbook has the feature.

Answer (score 1):

`getFileAsync` supports macOS now. You can find the doc here:

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync

Please let us know if you meet any issue when using the `getFileAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

getFileAsync is being added to Mac right now and it should be available soon in the coming weeks. I don't have a definite timeline yet. I can update this thread once it makes it to the release candidate.

Comment: Would the release also include `File.getSliceAsync()`, `File.closeAsync()`, and `Office.FileType.Compressed`?

Comment: Yes, they are part of the set as well.

Comment: It is going to be in August version -- usually available by around middle of the month.

Comment: Does this still look like it's coming mid August?

Comment: Any news on getFileAsync() for Excel for Mac?